# DOB in database, after one year I want to increment age and update into database also

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008

I am storing Date of Birth in database, after one year I want to increment age and update into database also.

Comment: There is simply not enough information here, show us some code, your class structure, at least.

Answer (score 6):

Store the date of birth. Make age a computed column:

```
CREATE TABLE [Table](
    /* Columns */
    [DateOfBirth] [date] NULL,
    [Age]  AS CASE
    WHEN DATEADD(year,-DATEDIFF(year,DateOfBirth,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) < DateOfBirth THEN
        DATEDIFF(year,DateOfBirth,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - 1
    ELSE
        DATEDIFF(year,DateOfBirth,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
    END,
    /* Constraints, etc */
)
```

This way you don't have to do any work yourself.

Answer (score 1):

you can implement the age as an calculated value. This way the age is always correct at the moment of querying (http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1682/using-computed-columns-in-sql-server-with-persisted-values/)